# How can I place my fixed alert message in front of HTML <dialog> element, opened with showModal()?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, daisyui

I have a `<dialog>` element styled with daisyUI and opened with [showModal()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal) using a `<button>` (here is [Tailwind play link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/GPmcfNKX10)):

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="my_modal_1.showModal()">open modal</button>

<dialog id="my_modal_1" class="modal modal-bottom z-10">
  <div class="modal-box">
    <h3 class="text-lg font-bold">Hello!</h3>
    <p class="py-4">Press ESC key or click the button below to close</p>
    <div class="modal-action">
      <form method="dialog">
        <button class="btn">Close</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</dialog>

<div class="fixed inset-x-0 bottom-0 z-20 h-64 bg-yellow-500 text-white">alert</div>
```

I want my fixed `<div>` in front of the modal. I've used `z-20` for my `<div>`, `z-10` for the dialog, but it doesn't work.

It works if I use `show()` instead of `showModal()`. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @MisterJojo thanks, if you have a source please write the answer, i'll accept it

Comment: I understood it's not possible. I was talking about making an answer here so I can accept you explanation and the answer.

Comment: I don't need "this type of confirmation" I only want to close the question with an answer... obviusly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want to achieve is impossible:

the `<dialog>` element was introduced into the HTML5 language in order to overcome disparities  on  `windows.alert()` and `windows.confirm()` methods of the JavaScript language.

In the case of using a `showModal()`, it behaves as an independent window **always placed in the foreground** of any previous view, and in your case, with no consider of the `z-index` CSS properties used outside of your dialog box, as would a JavaScript call to a `windows.alert()` command.